# O que devo retornar numa REST API quando os resultados são ou true ou false?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, get, response

Quando pesquiso uma informação no banco de dados e essa informação não é retornada(pois não existe), o que devo fazer? Preencher um objeto JSON para retorno do GET? E caso retorne false?

O response pode ser o status code 201 ou 404? Qual seria a melhor prática?

Comment: Editei para deixar mais claro o que você queria. Não é retornar true ou false e sim retornar uma resposta ou não. No seu caso é retornar ou não uma respsota.

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei, aliás achei a pergunta boa

Comment: E não é motivo para ser negativado tb !

Comment: Tranquilo. A pergunta ficou melhor! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

As API que utilizo atualmente retornam *NULL* em caso de **false** e *1* em caso de **true** em um sub array. Retornar 404 não é ideal, pois refere-se a "endereço não encontrado" e dá a entender que o cara requisitou para uma url errada. Recomendo retonar code 200 mesmo e sempre devolver um array com informações da consulta (quantidade de registros, paginas, etc) e um sub array dentro enfim contendo os dados.

Assim, caso façam uma requisição à sua API e ela cheque que não há registro a ser retornado, o usuário receberá code 200 e poderá ver que requisitou certo, porém não foram localizados registros no BD.

Comment: Aprendi (esses tempos na verdade) o status HTTP 204, que é um "Sucesso" que retorna "No Content" ("Sem Conteúdo"), o que seria uma espécie de "fracasso" (a requisição foi bem-sucedida, processada, e não retornou nada). Quem me ensinou disse que muita gente erra nisso, achando que códigos HTTP 2xx incluem apenas resultados "bem-sucedidos".